# How to wrap a java.util.Iterator to change the type of object being iterated

Tags: java, collections, guava, iterator-facade

I am providing some facade classes for a third-party API and I need to wrap an iterator so that I can replace what is iterated with my own facade object.

Here's a simplified version of my facade class that wraps an API class called **Item**

```
class FacadeItem {
    Item item;
    FacadeItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

The API provides an iterator of this form `Iterator<Item>`

I need to implement an iterator of this form `Iterator<FacadeItem>` that is backed by the iterator of the API.

I considered using the [ForwardingIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingIterator.html) from the Guava library as follows:

```
class FacadeItemIterator<FacadeItem> extends ForwardingIterator<Item> {

    final Iterator<Item> delegate; // backing iterator

    FacadeItemIterator(Iterator<Item> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override protected Iterator<Item> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public FacadeItem next() {
        return new FacadeItem(super.next());
    }
}
```

but the Override of `next()` is not permitted by the compiler because it is expecting the returned type to be **Item**, not **FacadeItem**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Iterator` interface isn't that big, so you could just write your own delegating iterator:

```
class FacadeIterator implements Iterator<FacadeItem> {
    private final Iterator<Item> delegate; // set in ctor

    @Override
    public FacadeItem next() {
        return new FacadeItem(delegate.next());
    }

    // the other two methods just delegate straight
}
```

and then

```
Iterator<FacadeItem> facadeIterator = new FacadeIterator(itemIterator);
```

If you're using Guava, you can use their [`Iterators.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#transform%28java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) static method to make one of these for you:

```
Iterator<FacadeItem> facadeIterator = Iterators.transform(itemIterator,
    /* anon class of Function<Item, FacadeItem> */);
```

And in Java 1.8, this option becomes really easy:

```
Iterator<FacadeItem> facadeIterator
    = Iterators.transform(itemIterator, FacadeItem::new)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. For completeness I'll just mention for those that may come to this later that the "other two methods" you need to override in your first solution are hasNext() and remove()